# How do I find open RemoteConnect Objects?

Tags: remote-access

The manual explains how you should close the connection if opened with

```
remote = RemoteConnect["host.example.com"]
```

with

```
DeleteObject[remote]
```

But what if I did not name it or have forgotten/lost the name? How do I find open connections created with RemoteConnect?

Answer (score 1):

Odd that there's no `RemoteConnections[]` function like there is `Processes[]`, `Streams[]`, `Links[]`, etc.

But I knew there had to be a way to check the thing was valid in the FE and from the `FormatValues` it seems you want to check `` SecureShellLink`Private`$RemoteUUIDTable ``.

No way to test it on my end since `RemoteConnect` doesn't support custom ports or anything, but you can give it a try.